# Fiz uma pergunta mas preciso de outra solução semelhante

Tags: suporte, perguntas

O que devo fazer quando eu fiz uma pergunta mas depois preciso de outra solução semelhante? Peço isso na mesma pergunta ou faço outra?

Acontece que encontrei um exemplo em um outro site que achei que solucionaria meu problema porém estava com alguns erros. Criei uma pergunta aqui e estão ajudando a solucionar. Porém ele ainda não vai se encaixar perfeitamente no que eu preciso.

Vou colocar a questão aqui só pra entenderem minha dúvida, se devo criar outra pergunta ou não, não é com a intenção de que seja respondida aqui.

*Eu preciso aplicar um estilo em um texto de um `RichEdit`, [a pergunta que fiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201288/aplicar-estilo-em-texto-de-um-richedit-no-delphi) foi pra me ajudar a solucionar o problema com o exemplo que achei. Porém este exemplo vai aplicando o estilo conforme eu digito e o que eu preciso mesmo é inserir um texto e depois aplicar um estilo em palavras específicas.*

Neste caso o que é o correto a se fazer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cada caso é um caso. O que você deve se perguntar é o seguinte: o problema que você enfrenta agora é o mesmo problema que você tinha antes?

Se sim, então sua pergunta não foi respondida corretamente - ou não foi formulada com todo o detalhamento necessário. Nesse caso, é válido editar a pergunta. Talvez você não tenha mais tanta atenção nessa pergunta, por ela já ter sido respondida antes... Daí você pode levantar o assunto no chat, ou oferecer uma recompensa. Infelizmente essas coisas requerem mais reputação do que você tem agora, mas é só questão de tempo até você ser capaz de fazer essas coisas.

Agora, se o problema que você tem agora é diferente do problema inicial, então você deve abrir outra pergunta mesmo. Parece ser o caso da pergunta que você menciounou.

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta que postei me ajudaria a resolver o meu problema, mas caso eu não consiga solucioná-la eu precisaria saber se posso criar outra pergunta mesmo que sejam semelhantes. Mas consegui entender. Vou tentar solucionar, eu conseguindo ou não vou postar aqui pra ajudar a comunidade também. Vlws

Answer (score 4):

Faça outra, já que mesmo sendo relacionado e parecido o problema é outro.